# Scraping multiple pages for parsing in Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, urllib2

I'm trying to scrape multiple pages off of a single website for BeautifulSoup to parse. So far, I've tried using urllib2 to do this, but have been encountering some problems. What I've attempted is:

```
import urllib2,sys
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

for numb in ('85753', '87433'):
    address = ('http://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/ws/index.php?pid=' + numb)
html = urllib2.urlopen(address).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

title = soup.find("span", {"class":"paperstitle"})
date = soup.find("span", {"class":"docdate"})
span = soup.find("span", {"class":"displaytext"})  # span.string gives you the first bit
paras = [x for x in span.findAllNext("p")]

first = title.string
second = date.string
start = span.string
middle = "\n\n".join(["".join(x.findAll(text=True)) for x in paras[:-1]])
last = paras[-1].contents[0]

print "%s\n\n%s\n\n%s\n\n%s\n\n%s" % (first, second, start, middle, last)
```

This only gives me results for the second number in the `numb` sequence, i.e. http://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/ws/index.php?pid=87433. I also made some attempts at using mechanize, but had no success. Ideally what I would like to be able to do is have a page, with a list of links, and then automatically select a link, pass the HTML off to BeautifulSoup, and then move to the next link in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the rest of the code inside the loop. Right now you're iterating over both items in  the tuple, but at the end of the iteration only the last item remains assigned to `address` which subsequently gets parsed outside the loop.

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tidier solution (using lxml):

```
import lxml.html as lh

root_url = 'http://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/ws/index.php?pid='
page_ids = ['85753', '87433']

def scrape_page(page_id):
    url = root_url + page_id
    tree = lh.parse(url)

    title = tree.xpath("//span[@class='paperstitle']")[0].text
    date = tree.xpath("//span[@class='docdate']")[0].text
    text = tree.xpath("//span[@class='displaytext']")[0].text_content()

    return title, date, text

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for page_id in page_ids:
        title, date, text = scrape_page(page_id)
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually like this better than the BeautifulSoup method.

Comment: I like this solution. How would you save the pages you're scraping?

Comment: @Joe should be as simple as the 3rd example here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples

Answer (score 1):

I think you just missed the indentation in the loop :

```
import urllib2,sys
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

for numb in ('85753', '87433'):
    address = ('http://www.presidency.ucsb.edu/ws/index.php?pid=' + numb)
    html = urllib2.urlopen(address).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

    title = soup.find("span", {"class":"paperstitle"})
    date = soup.find("span", {"class":"docdate"})
    span = soup.find("span", {"class":"displaytext"})  # span.string gives you the first bit
    paras = [x for x in span.findAllNext("p")]

    first = title.string
    second = date.string
    start = span.string
    middle = "\n\n".join(["".join(x.findAll(text=True)) for x in paras[:-1]])
    last = paras[-1].contents[0]

    print "%s\n\n%s\n\n%s\n\n%s\n\n%s" % (first, second, start, middle, last)
```

I think this should solve the problem..

Comment: That was the problem. The answer above pointed it out. Thank you very much for your help.